# define route in python flask for url ending with anything but not numbers alone

Tags: python, regex, flask, routes

Here is my python code

```
@app.route("/<regex('.*\/([0-9]+)'):param>/")
def go_to(param):
    return param
```

I'm using Flask Framework.The above route allows urls ending with numbers only to access `go_to` function.
How to define a route for urls ending with anything other than `numbers alone`.
For example `www.example.com/asd/ase/vi89` fall in number alone category,similarly 
`www.example.com/as/er/_67io` also fall in that category.

Comment: Why does the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Put an end marker ('$') to end of the regex if you want your urls to end with numbers.